# Use Input Stream multiple times

Tags: java

```
for (File fileEntry : dir.listFiles()) {
    String strXMLFilename = null;
    strXMLFilename = fileEntry.getName();
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(strXMLFilename);
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod();
    post.setRequestBody(input);
    .....
    .....
    .....
}
```

when ever my for loop runs, `InputStream input = new FileInputStream(strXMLFilename);` this line works fine. But, when the second time it is entering in to for block the re is a problem with this line. I hope the input stream is not reading the file properly. i tried by closing the input stream, even though it is not working.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Do you get an exception?

Comment: There is *what* 'problem with this line'? And there is no multiple ue of any InputStream here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read it many times you should either use the reset method after reading of BufferedInputStream or use a byte[] which I think is more apropriate..